# Why does react turn my state into [object object]

Tags: reactjs, object, state, use-state

I've got this straightforward component:

Here it is on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-architecture-fgvwg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
function Home() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(name);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={setName}
          type="text"
          placeholder="name"
        />
        <button type="submit">
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

As soon as I click in the input box, it turns into `[object object]` and I'd love to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing a value to your `name` variable `onChange`. `onChange` returns `event` which you have to get the value from and set the name that way.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(name);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.currentTarget.value)} type="text" placeholder="name" />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

The update here is the `onChange` attribute. You are grabbing the event `e` and setting the name to whatever that currentTarget value is.

```js
onChange = { (e) => setName(e.currentTarget.value) }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me insane because I've used this in another project, and it actually works OK, I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

Your onChange handler receives a [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) object. If you want the new value you'll need to get it from the event: `event.target.value`:

```
<input
  value={name}
  onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
  type="text"
  placeholder="name"
/>
```

When you cast a value to a string, like when calling `console.log`, the value's [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method is invoked, which for objects returns [object Object] by default.

Answer (score 0):

You had `onChange` set to `setName`. Setname is a function used to update the value of name.

You need to write a function to handle the name value being updating when the user types in a name. Set `onChange` equal to that function:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(name);
  };

  function handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="name"
        />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Copy paste error. Your `handleChange` has a prevent default :)